# Why does Jetpack insert it's script outside the <html> tag?

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I went to validate my HTML with the W3C validator and I got this error:

Line 463, Column 77: Stray start tag script.
…t src="http://stats.wordpress.com/e-201338.js" type="text/javascript">

This script is insterted by the Jetpack plug-in for the statistics, but it is inserted outside of the html tags, which ruins my validation!! Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: what theme are you using? where is the `wp_footer()` function in your theme?

Comment: Ahhh this might be it! I do not have a wp_footer hehe. I am building my own theme.

Comment: You can post it as an answer, it's working now :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your theme calls the [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) function before the closing body tag, and scripts will be output in the correct location.